# pagination numbers aren"t showing laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-pagination

Pagination works fine when i search for hotels pages, 
but when i select to view an hotel with it propre rooms ,
i  get the hotel but  the rooms aren't paginated
like i got 3 rooms instead of 100{paginated} 
also no page numbers

What i m doing wrong

the code from controller::

```
{
        $hotel = Hotel::where('slug', $slug)->first();  
        $hotel_id = $hotel->id;     
        $rooms = Room::where('hotel_id', $hotel_id)->paginate(3);
        return view('hotels.show',['hotel' => $hotel, 'rooms' => $rooms ]);
}
```

the blade html:

```
<div> {{ $hotel->title }} </div>

@foreach($rooms as $room)
<div>Room: {{ $room->title }} </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

paginate (3) means its give you 3 room in every page.. if you want to paginate 100 in every page then you should use paginate (100) instead of 3.

And if you want to show the links/pages then just simply call $rooms->links()

Your code looks like:-

```
<div> {{ $hotel->title }} </div>

@foreach($rooms as $room)
<div>Room: {{ $room->title }} </div>
@endforeach

<div> {{ $rooms->links() }} </div>
```